# How can I activate the 'say' command from the keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I love the 'say' command in OS X. It's quite possibly the most fun little part of the Mac that I've seen in a while.

However, having to go to Terminal every time I want to use it is a bit of a drag. I'd like to make it a keyboard shortcut.

So: How can I tell OS X to 'say' whatever text I have selected with a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to System Preferences, click the "Speech" icon, then click the "Text to Speech" tab. Then simply check the "Speak selected text when the key is pressed" box.

Text you have selected will be spoken when you press the selected key combination.

[image]

Comment: You win, I'm deleting my answer :)

Answer (score -1):

With macOS Big Sur 11.3.1, to read any written text (in your browser, text editor program, pdf ..), you first need to enable it in *System Preferences > Accessibility*. In the left pane, select *Spoken Content*. And select *Speak selection*.

[image: Enable Speak selection in System Preferences]

You can also choose the shortcut to activate this function: **click on *Options* and choose the Keyboard shortcut** you prefer.

[image: Choose the shortcut and options of the Speak selection]

Then, to use Speak selection, just select any text in a document (text, doc, in your browser, in a pdf … ) and use your shortcut. It should read your text out loud and display a pop up menu where you can pause, stop, control the speed …

Comment: Why do you think it does not answer?  Could you explain ?
The question asks for a way to use a shortcut to read any text, and I explain how to enable that functionality , choose the shortcut and use the shortcut with the options in the pop-up menu.
Moreover, it is updated answers from the accepted answer, for the new macOS Big Sur 11.3.1.

Comment: I made it a bit more obvious that the answer explains how to set a shortcut.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I thought it was how to make it work in Terminal

Comment: thank you @nohillside for making it clearer.